# cw-144 oscillation problems

Tags: bitcoin-cash, difficulty, hashpower

I am starting to get into Difficulty Algorithms and attacks on them. I came across cw-144 which used to be BCH's DAA at least until mid 2020 (recent developments do not interest me and this is not the point of this post). It became apparent it was vulnerable to rational miners moving between BTC and BCH mining. This was caused because cw-144 is a SMA DAA.

I couldn't manage to grasp why the fact the average is flat (and not EMA or LWMA) causes these oscillations while EMA, LWMA don't. I know this has something to do with the fact that blocks going out of the simple average window have the same effect as them going into the window but I didn't understand why that is (mentioned [here](https://read.cash/@jtoomim/bch-upgrade-proposal-use-asert-as-the-new-daa-1d875696)). I would much appreciate help with this.

I also added a graph from the above link showing the oscillations.
[image]

Comment: I see some people are voting to close this question as "off-topic", however I think the topic of difficulty adjustment algorithms, miner switching and difficulty oscillations is very much applicable to Bitcoin, even if the discussion includes an altcoin.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad I agree as well. Looks like that folks are trying to close BCH as "off-topic".

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg BCH is indeed off-topic on Bitcoin Stack Exchange, see the relevant [meta discussion](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1005/121614). Whether this question specifically is off-topic is debatable, but it was closed as such by votes from multiple people, and until the author or someone else edits it to address the reason for closing, the vote stands.